# protection.setUnprotectedRanges - Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to setup unprotected ranges in a google sheet, I have quite a few ranges to unprotect at the same time. Therefore I'd like to store them in an array and then unprotect all at the same time. However I'm having trouble using the array in the protection.setUnprotectedRanges statement (shown by the *** in the code below).

Can I use an array without declaring every element within it?

Thanks

```
 function myFunction2() {

 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
 var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protect Sheet');
var unprotected = new Array(26);

 unprotected[0] = sheet.getRange(1,1,10,1);
 unprotected[1] = sheet.getRange(1,5,10,2);
 unprotected[2] = sheet.getRange(1,20,10,2);

 protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected[]]); // *** How to I use the whole array with setUnprotectedRanges, without declaring every element within the array in the statement (as below)
 //protection.setUnprotectedRanges([unprotected[0],unprotected[1]]); // don't want to use this method
 // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
 // permission comes from a group, the script will throw an exception upon removing the group.
 var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
 protection.addEditor(me);
 protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
 if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
   protection.setDomainEdit(false);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the whole [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) by its name, `unprotected`, to the method, `setUnprotectedRanges()`:

```
function myFunction2() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var protection = sheet.protect().setDescription('Protect Sheet');
  var unprotected = [];

  unprotected[0] = sheet.getRange(1,1,10,1);
  unprotected[1] = sheet.getRange(1,5,10,2);
  unprotected[2] = sheet.getRange(1,20,10,2);

  protection.setUnprotectedRanges(unprotected);
  ...
}
```